# CMake with 2 Project and a shared Library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a repository with 2 Projects, which both link a single (self-made) library which is also contained in the repository. I also include some dependencies, which both projects use.

The project structure is as follows:

```
repo/
├─ dependencies/
│  ├─ audeo/
│  ├─ argparse/
│  ├─ json
├─ my-library/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ ...
├─ projet2/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ ...
├─ projet1/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ ...
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

I don't know how to utilize this. I already tried to set up a project, but I ran into numerous problems, which I don't want to further go into detail about.
My question is whether there are examples of this kind of project structure or if you have good practice advice, or if this problem has a common name that I can research.

## Edit:

I will post my CMake files and the link to the current state of the source code (Disclaimer: the second project is not already included).

Content of `repo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(root)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# dependencies
add_subdirectory(dependencies/dep1)
add_subdirectory(dependencies/dep2)
add_subdirectory(dependencies/dep3)

# sub-projects
add_subdirectory(my-library)
add_subdirectory(project1)
add_subdirectory(project2)
```

---

Content of `my-library/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(my-library)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(my-library STATIC
        src/World.cpp include/World.h
        include/Player.h
        include/Position.h
        include/Audio/Effect.h
        include/Audio/Music.h
        include/Audio/Audio.h)

target_link_libraries(my-library PRIVATE
        dep1::dep1
        dep2::dep2)
```

---

Content of `projet1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(project1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(project1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(project1 PRIVATE
        dep1::dep1
        dep3::dep3
)
```

---

Content of `projet2/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(project2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(project2 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(project2 PRIVATE
        dep2::dep2
)
```

Since my source code is open source anyway I will post the [link](https://github.com/mobergmann/position-based-ambience-sound) to my repository. But please note that the names of the projects may differ as well as the structure.

### Problem

My Problem is, that I cannot include one dependency (warning! this is a translation):

```
fatal error: dep1/dep1.hpp: file or directory not found
   11 | #include <dep1/dep1.hpp>
```

And I want to be able to include my library in Angle-bracket form.

Comment: hope this can help you https://cmake.org/examples/

Comment: Why do you need to have two projects in a single repo? Anyway, I'd recommend decoupling them completely or coupling them even more tightly, either make two proper projects, or make a single project with several executables that do similar yet different things, while having exact same dependencies and configuration. What you're trying to do is something inbetween, and I'm not convinced you actually meant to do that.

Comment: My main problem is, that my library also depend on the dependencies and I cannot include some dependence in my library: `#include <audeo/audeo.hpp>` with an file or folder not found error on compilation.

Comment: @Moritz: So you problem is to **build the library** itself, not to build two projects which use the same library. In CMake there is no best way to organize a project, so there is a little sense to ask about it. However, we could help you to improve **your project**. For that you need to show the **code** (`CMakeLists.txt` files) of your project, and to specify its **problems**.

Comment: I have added the general problem description of my CMake. I hope that this helps.

Comment: `target_include_directories` uncomend it an add the include directories. `d I cannot include some` Please post the error message.

Comment: Change PRIVATE to PUBLIC if dependencies should be inherited.

Comment: Thanks! I can now comile and run my applications. But one question still is not answered. Can I somehow include my own library in Angle-bracket form?

Comment: Of course you can. You just need to pass correct include directories into consuming target. In your case that would be `repo/` directory.